# Stubbing an ES6 class method using Mocha and Sinon in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, stub

Is there a way to stub an ES6 class method using Mocha/Sinon?

I'm trying to do this...

```
sinon.stub(Factory, 'announce');
```

but I just get the following error...

```
TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property announce as function
```

Comment: Shouldn't you pass `Factory.prototype`? I guess it's not a static method.

Comment: I didn't realise that ES6 classes still used .prototype! Want to post an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instance methods are still placed on the prototype object of a class to be inherited from, not on its constructor, even if the `class` syntax obscures that a bit. Use

```
sinon.stub(Factory.prototype, 'announce');
```

Comment: and you can use `stub(obj, 'meth').callsFake(fn)` if you need to override the function. https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.1.5/stubs/